# Django Channels - Connect to External Websocket

Tags: django, websocket, channel

I'm new to Django and Channels and so far I couldn't find any solution to the issue that I face:

I need to communicate with an external WebSocket, to process received data and then sent it to some Channels groups or maybe start some Celery tasks based on that output.

As I've understood it's not a good practice to put that logic inside Consumer. What is the right way of doing this in Django?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It'S probably not at all best practice to do it in Django in first place. Django is a Web Framework, that processes individual http requests. Connecting to websockets for potentially longer running process should happen in another component of your architecture.